# 2 RelativeLayouts not sizing correctly according to my understanding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am very new to this whole android thing, and I am facing some troubles here.

I am following a tutorial on fragments, and ViewList.  I am trying to add two fragments, to each individual RelativeLayout.  I am also setting the `layout_weitght` on of these RelativeLayouts, but this does not seem to work as I understand it should.

Here is the code for adding the fragments.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //add fragments
    //get Assessor object passed in intent and createNewInstance of fragment, setting defaults
    Assessor assessor = new Assessor();
    assessor.set_name("TestName");

    user_profile_fragment frag = user_profile_fragment.newInstance(assessor);
    ListFragment fragList = ListFragment.newInstance();

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.userProfileContainer, frag);
    transaction.add(R.id.listContainer, fragList);
    transaction.commit();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Here is the xml for the activity I am calling the onCreate on, and trying to add the fragments:

```
<layout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.andre.vehicleasseessing.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/userProfileContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/listContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the output, currently:

[image: Incorrect output]

From my understanding, setting the `layout_weight`, should make the output look a little bit different.  The user container, should take up about a quarter of the screen, and the list, should take up about three quarters of the screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Please share your comment if you down voted so that I can improve my question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LinearLayout` instead.

Use `layout_sum` attribute of parent linear layout with value **4**.

And subsequent LinearLayout should have layout weight set as required.
In your case, layout weights should be **1** and **3** respectively.

**Update**:

It is recommended that you set the layout height to **0dp** for each child to occupy equal space. You can refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) for further information.

Comment: Thanks.  After changing to LinearLayout, this worked in the sense that it made my listview larger, but it seemed to have stretched over the "TestName", and that was no longer visible.  To make this work fully, I had to set the layout_height to "0dp" on both child elements.

Comment: It was expected that you'd change the layout height to 0dp since it is most relevant when layout weights are used.

Comment: It is not so obvious when you are new to all of this. If you update your answer to show this, I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to set layout_height attribute of both nested relative layouts to 0dp, then weights should be respected appropriately.